# Is there a way to pass custom XML attributes to a class that extends View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

Assuming I have something that looks like this:

```
public class MyExcellentView extends View{
  //etc. etc.

}
```

and in the xml I use it thusly:

```
<com.my.package.MyExcellentView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 myCustomAttribute="100"
/>
```

Is there a way to get access to `myCustomAttribute` within `MyExcellentView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the way you do it:

```
public MyExcellentView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable. MyCustomView);
            int customAtt = a.getInteger(R.styleable. MyCustomView_yourCustomAttribute, defaultValue);
            a.recycle();
}
```

But you also have to declare the attribute in the resources like so in attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
      <attr name="yourCustomAttribute"/>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Also in order to use it you have to do it like this:

```
<com.my.package.MyExcellentView
  xmlns:customAtts="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.package"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  customAtts:myCustomAttribute="100"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: thanks... I just found the actual docs for this (I don't believe they were there the last time I looked) http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: awesome, no problem :D